# Maven: Identify the correct dependency from given code

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

What is the best way to find the right dependency for a used class that are part of the maven-online-repository?

As far I see it is this approach:

1. lookup the import (e.g. org.whatever.X;) from your code at the maven-repository online (search.maven.org).
2. Pick one of the result list and include it in the dependency section of the POM.
3. Hope the chosen version and artifact of the dependency matches your requirements (compiling, runtime). If not try another artifact or version.

Comment: What do you mean with `from your code`? Is this a (Maven/Gradle/...) project?

Comment: "What is the best way to handle the problem of finding the right jar/dependency for a used class" - I thought this was the exact problem maven was trying to solve!

Comment: As long the tool is not looking in my code and finds the right jar for me BUT I need to put a dependency manually in my POM I think I need to find it and not maven.

Comment: With respect to 3: you can always write your code to match that specific version if they aren't binary compatible. You'll probably want to search for the project's own website and find out from the authors/contributors what the recommended latest and/or best supported stable version is, or which one contains a certain feature that you need in your code. There won't be too much trial and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to share my way of doing it. What do you mean by "finding the ... for a used class that are part of the ..."? Do you mean that the dependancy is already used in somewhere else, or that you only know the package name that you may need?

I would first check which version I need for the current project.
If I'm working on a team project and someone has used the dependency in somewhere else, I would check their pom (to ensure we are using the same dependency).

Then I would look up the dependency in Maven repo and include it in my pom.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I know the package name to import in the code. But then I need to find the jar/dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, yes this is what you have to do to obtain libraries/modules for your project.

Something that's helped me out though with this specific problem: versioning. You can set the versions you need for each of your dependencies with `<properties>` -> `<gson.version>2.8.1</gson.version>` (for example). That way, you can guarantee that your build matches with the reqs of the class or type of code you're trying to implement.

Maven doc ref: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties